# IBOutlets' constraints conflict

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `NSLayoutConstraint` conflict when I try to manually set my `IBOutlet`'s constraints. Essentially, I am only putting views in the storyboard to get a general sense of how they would look and then creating `IBOutlet`s to reference them. But all constraints are added in code:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view2: UView2!
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        view2.addSubview(name)

        //add constraints
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view1, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view1, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: -self.view.frame.height * 0.07).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view1, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 0.8, constant: 0).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view1, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 0.4, constant: 0).active = true

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view2, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view1, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view2, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view1, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view2, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view1, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.height * 0.01).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view2, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 0.1, constant: 0).active = true



      }
 }
```

The `NSLayoutConstraint` conflict goes away when I just create the view in code, i.e. `var view2 = UIView()` or if I comment out `view2`'s constraints. I don't understand.

EDIT: Based on the log, the problem seems to be `NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint` and `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height'` for `view2` although there is no auto layout constraints set in storyboard. What confuses my now is why doesn't `view1` have this problem, since they were both added in the storyboard?

Comment: Have you deleted all the constraints from SB?

Comment: Yes. I double checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set constraints on `view2` in the storyboard, so Xcode is secretly adding constraints for you. What you need to do is add constraints for `view2` in the storyboard, and (because you don't really want them at runtime) tell Xcode to remove those constraints at build time:

[image: "Remove at build time" checkbox in the Size inspector]

Comment: I created a dummy constraint and selected that option and it worked! Thanks, although If I may ask you another question -- I tried doing it in code `view2.removeConstraints(view2.constraints)` but that was effective, what is the difference between "Remove at build time" and that line of code in `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: @user245954 - The choice of "Remove at build time" is just a more efficient approach, preventing the constraint from being created at run time only to then subsequently remove/deactivate it. Also, be aware that not all constraints for a view are in the `view2.constraints` collection, but rather may be attached to the nearest common parent (e.g. the superview). By choosing the "remove at build time", you get out of the silliness of figuring out which constraints are where. (Frankly, if I were going to programmatically remove/activate/alter them, I'd build a IB outlet collection and use that.)